# Some Doubts about Independence of Perpendicular Vectors

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

Imagine an inclined plane inclined at an angle x radians, and a mass sliding down under the influence of gravity.

It's component responsible for its slide down the slope would be $g \sin x$ and perpendicular to this component would be the vector component $g \cos x$.

My teacher very briefly told me that perpendicular vectors are independent of each other and I interpreted it as, in the above example the vector $g \sin x$ is completely independent of the vector $g \cos x$.

Thus, the mass will slide down with the acceleration $g \sin x$, no matter even if I add some external force along $g \cos x$ .

For example, if I have a rope along the direction $g \cos x$ and I tie it to the mass and exert force in the direction $g \cos x$ from under the inclined plane, the acceleration of the mass $g \sin x$ should remain independent as I applied a perpendicular force (vector) but it seems counter-intuitive as I think the mass should stop in its path and not slide down the slope.

Kindly explain where my reasoning was wrong.

Comment: For it to stop there would be needed a force in the $\sin x$ direction to counter gravity.  In your intuition, where does that force come from?

Comment: In my intuition, I imagine the force from under the inclined plane along the direction of g cos x perpendicular to the component g sin x which implies perpendicular to the ramp. Like a rope pulling the mass on the inclined ramp perpendicular to it , sort of jamming it and not allowing it's sliding movement

Comment: @wizard Objects only "jam" in the presence of friction. All of these idealized scenarios are frictionless.

Comment: Does that mean that in a frictionless environment even if a perpendicular force (however large in magnitude) is applied on an object against a wall , it will slide down with "g"?

Comment: @wizard Yes, it will

Comment: You have inaccurate pre-conceptions that are going to cause problems as you try to learn physics.  Instead of debating your teacher, try to keep an open mind.

Comment: Don't the third, fourth and fifth comments above answer your question?

Comment: @wizard, OK.  It's a mathematical fact that perpendicular vectors are mathematically independent.  That is something that you just need to accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to be careful about vocabulary. Two vectors are linearly independent if one is not a multiple of the other. That is, if they do not lie along the same line.

Your teacher is trying to express a different idea, and there isn't good name for it other than perpendicular or orthogonal. It relates to projections and the dot product.

Suppose a vector $\vec v_1$is parallel to the ground. Another vector $\vec v_2$ forms some angle $\theta$ to it in a vertical plane. The noon sun shines down. How long is the shadow of $\vec v_2$? That is the projection of $\vec v_2$ on $\vec v_1$.

The idea is

- If $\theta < \pi/2$, the shadow is in the direction of $\vec v_1$.
- If $\theta < \pi/2$, the shadow is in the other direction.
- If $\theta = \pi/2$, the shadow has $0$ length.

Now suppose $\vec v_2$ is a force vector acting on an object.

Now suppose we have an object. Without any force, the shadow has a constant velocity along $\vec v_1$. What happens to the shadow of the object when force  $\vec v_2$ acts on it?

The object will acquire a sideways velocity that will not affect the shadow. The projection of $\vec v_2$ on $\vec v_1$ will change the velocity of the shadow. But if $\theta = \pi/2$, the change will be $0$.

As an aside that will be useful in the future, note that

$$\text{projection} = \frac{\vec v_2 \cdot \vec v_1}{v_1}$$